# checkbox helper sending an extra param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

```
<%= form_for list do |f| %> <!-- This might be an issue in production mode -->
    <%= f.fields_for l = list.list_items.build, index: l.id do |list_item| %>
            <td><%= list_item.check_box :user_item_id, { checked: false, include_hidden: false }, item.id, "nil" %></td> <!-- checkboxes seem problematic, try check_box_tag? -->
            <td><%= item.name %></td> 
            <td>$<%= number_with_precision(item.price, :precision => 2) %></td>
            <td><%= list_item.number_field :quantity, 
                                                                            min: 1,
                                                                            class: "num"%></td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I have three of these on my page and all three are checked, Rails will send an extra unchecked value for each form. Why is this?

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sn2HLFvVLX7ZFxBTHvRGz25H+bbyiVl8E8Kok5J7788q8WA33U8RpWmLXjU2GTjD2ybW7RMaiX1CwLJ6oCLXmQ==", "list"=>{"list_item"=>[{"user_item_id"=>"nil"}, {"user_item_id"=>"19", "quantity"=>"1"}, {"user_item_id"=>"nil"}, {"user_item_id"=>"20", "quantity"=>"2"}, {"user_item_id"=>"nil"}, {"user_item_id"=>"21", "quantity"=>"3"}], "name"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create List"}
```

However if I turn hidden fields off, I get other issues with my forms "stealing" each-other's data when a preceding box is left unchecked. For example here I left the first form unchecked:

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qszyk+q+pJ77WuDh2/K2S8lTuBD99DptwqeEdDI4U+4yQBWIbCSYRUvGrofzH8hHfDKXSxxn6myTpZ6dAGFruA==", "list"=>{"list_item"=>[{"quantity"=>"1", "user_item_id"=>"20"}, {"quantity"=>"2", "user_item_id"=>"21"}, {"quantity"=>"3"}], "name"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create List"}

Notice how the first unchecked form neglected to set the user_item_id to "nil", and instead left the param out completely and stole the next form's user_item_id, thus messing up my quantity values (which I set to the same as before).

Why is this?

PS: I originally had "nil" just nil, but doing so prevents the unchecked value from being passed in any case and I was having issues with the forms stealing values from each other like I posted above. If anyone could tell me how to make it so that an unchecked box means that my fields_for will not be submitted at all that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is done by rails so that the right value is sent when the checkbox is unchecked.

When you don't check the checkbox the value of the hidden field(added by the checkbox helper) reaches your server, as unchecked checkboxes are not sent by the browsers.

In the other hand, when you check it, the last value with the same name wins, meaning the checked value will be sent to the server and everything will work as you expect.

from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box):

> Gotcha
>
> The HTML specification says unchecked check boxes are not successful,
>   and thus web browsers do not send them. Unfortunately this introduces
>   a gotcha: if an Invoice model has a paid flag, and in the form that
>   edits a paid invoice the user unchecks its check box, no paid
>   parameter is sent. So, any mass-assignment idiom like 
>   @invoice.update(params[:invoice]) wouldn't update the flag.
>
> To prevent this the helper generates an auxiliary hidden field before
>   the very check box. The hidden field has the same name and its
>   attributes mimic an unchecked check box.
>
> This way, the client either sends only the hidden field (representing
>   the check box is unchecked), or both fields. Since the HTML
>   specification says key/value pairs have to be sent in the same order
>   they appear in the form, and parameters extraction gets the last
>   occurrence of any repeated key in the query string, that works for
>   ordinary forms.